# Delete SQL query with nested select query

Tags: sql, sql-delete

How do I delete all records that satisfy this query? That is, how do I transform this into a delete query.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Data_Pro_Encounter_Info]
WHERE [subject_id] IN
(SELECT [subject_id]
  FROM [imucsigrp].[dbo].[Data_Pro_Patient_Info]
  Where [username] = 'ZGWATA')
```

Comment: Use Delete * instead of Select *

Comment: Have you tried to simply replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE`?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM [Data_Pro_Encounter_Info] 
WHERE [subject_id] IN (SELECT [subject_id] 
                       FROM [imucsigrp].[dbo].[Data_Pro_Patient_Info]
                       WHERE [username] = 'ZGWATA')
```